# To define these two class " typedef map<C, B::iterator> A ; typedef list<D, A::iterator> B "?

Tags: c++, stl

To define these two class

```
typedef map<C, B::iterator> A;
typedef list<D, A::iterator> B;
```

The class A and B mutual contain each other's iterator.
The compiler complains about above statement.
How to solve the problem ?

iammilind says it is impossible. but this logic relationship appears, for example a priority queue. So any one have workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's **not possible**.
`A` and `B` are interdependent, so at least one of them has to be forward declared to support the other.
But the `typedef` types cannot be forward declared as `class/struct`.

Comment: Sometime, we unfortunately encounter this situation. For example, with a priority queue with function that increase or decrease the priority.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this using just typedefs.

Substituting B for its typedef:

```
typedef map<C, B::iterator> A;
typedef list<D, A::iterator> B;
```

becomes:

```
typedef map<C, list<D, A::iterator>::iterator> A;
typedef list<D, A::iterator> B;
```

Then substituting A for its typedef:

```
typedef map<C, list<D, map<C, list<D, A::iterator>::iterator>::iterator>::iterator> A;
typedef list<D, A::iterator> B;
```

This substitution would go forever without collapsing...

edit:
I should point out that if you make wrapper classes around the map and list, you can forward declare the classes.

Comment: You yourself aren't sure if it works or not. Have you tried compiling it ? This answer is not practical and it doesn't work.

Comment: @iammilind I'm just answering the question.  I know forward declaration is necessary but I don't believe typedefs can be forward declared.